# Invalid value for prop in <input> tag in React file

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, react-props

react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/attribute-behavior
at input
at div
at div
at form
at ExpenseForm (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:607:90)
at div
at NewExpense
at div
at App

```
import React, { useState } from "react" import "./ExpenseForm.css" const ExpenseForm = (props) => { const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("") const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState("") const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState("")

//   const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({ //     enteredTitle: "", //     enteredAmount: "", //     enteredDate: "", //   })

const titleChangeHandler = (event) => { setEnteredTitle(event.target.value) // setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredTitle: event.target.value }) // setUserInput((prevValue) => { //   return { ...prevValue, enteredTitle: event.target.value } // }) }

const amountChangeHandler = (event) => { setEnteredAmount(event.target.value) // setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredAmount: event.target.value }) }

const dateChangeHandler = (event) => { setEnteredDate(event.target.value) // setUserInput({ ...userInput, enteredDate: event.target.value }) }

const submitHander = (event) => { event.preventDefault()
const expenseData = {
  title: enteredTitle,
  amount: enteredAmount,
  date: new Date(enteredDate),
}

props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData)

setEnteredTitle("")
setEnteredAmount("")
setEnteredDate("")
}

return ( <form onSubmit={submitHander}> <div className="new-expense__controls"> <div className="new-expense__control"> <label>TItle</label> <input
            type="text"
            value={setEnteredTitle}
            onChange={titleChangeHandler}
          /> </div> <div className="new-expense__control"> <label>Amount</label> <input
            type="number"
            min="0.01"
            step="0.01"
            value={setEnteredAmount}
            onChange={amountChangeHandler}
          /> </div> <div className="new-expense__control"> <label>Date</label> <input
            type="date"
            min="2020-01-01"
            max="2050-12-31"
            setEnteredDate={setEnteredDate}
            onChange={dateChangeHandler}
          /> </div> <div className="new-expense__actions"> <button type="submit">Add Expense</button> </div> </div> </form> ) } 
export default ExpenseForm
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the value of the `value` prop on each `input` element. Instead of passing the `setState` function to each of them, pass the `state`.

For example
`value={setEnteredTitle}`

to
`value={enteredTitle}`

I believe this will fix.